# Add ManyToMany in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a webservice where I want to add rdp config files to a certain contract number.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from program.models import contract,rdp
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='login')
def add_rdp(request):
        if request.method == "POST":

                get_rdp = (request.POST.get('rdp', ''))
                get_number = (request.POST.get('contract_number',''))

                new_rdp = rdp(config = get_rdp).save()

                for new_contract in contract.objects.filter(number = get_number):
                        new_rdp.contract.add(new_contract)

        return render(request, 'add_rdp.html')
```

models.py

```
class contract(models.Model):
        server = models.ForeignKey(server)
        number = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 64)

class rdp(models.Model):
        contract = models.ForeignKey(contract)
        config = models.TextField()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Integrity Error
(1048, "Column 'contract_id' cannot be null")
```

Since this approach worked for me in another webapp in Django, I can't figure out why this is not working.

Comment: I think the issue is that when you create the new_rdp instance, you didn't assign a contract value to it, since it is not nullable.

Comment: rdp has a foreign key to contract, not a many-to-many relationship.  You cannot `.add()` things to it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the model instance and then just add it to your 'new_rdp'. You could do something like this:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def add_rdp(request):
        if request.method == "POST":

                get_rdp = (request.POST.get('rdp', ''))
                get_number = (request.POST.get('contract_number',''))

                for new_contract in contract.objects.all():
                        if new_contract.number == get_number:
                                new_rdp = rdp(config = get_rdp, contract = new_contract).save()

        return render(request, 'add_rdp.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because You calling `save()` when no contract attached.

You can change definition of model:

```
class rdp(models.Model):
        contract = models.ForeignKey(contract, blank = True)
        config = models.TextField()
```

Comment: it is not only blank=True, it should be also null=True

Comment: Is your approach combined with your change in the models also legit practice or is this just some kind of work around ?